# How to write a Icon Handlers for explorer.exe in Java

Tags: java, windows, explorer

First of all, I'm a java developer and I am currently working on a small application for Windows only.

In my application, I wish to do as dropbox or tortoise do : add an overlay icon in windows explorer to show the user some state of files managed by my application. (I want the icon of the file change depending on some data stored in the file)

Is it possible to do so in Java ? Do you have examples ?

If it is doable but not efficient, how would you do instead ?

Thanks in advance

Fluminis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible to do this via JNI - you would need to hook into the Windows registry and from there into the Explorer shell, probably into the various file classes held there.

However, unless you have at least some familiarity with C++ and the windows API, you are unlikely to be able to achieve this.

Java is not the ideal language for what you want to do.